# Extracting binary digits of machine precision numbers

Tags: performance-tuning, machine-precision, digits

Currently, I am developing an octree data structure. And I need it to be fast. To this end, I would like to have a fast way to extract the $m$ binary digits "after the dot" of each entry in a matrix of machine precision numbers. This matrix is of size $n \times d$ where $d$ is the space dimension (say $d=3$) and represents a set of $n$ points (shift and rescaled to lie in the unit box) to which the octree has to adapt. The number $n$ is typically in the range of a couple of 100 thousands and a few million. So, the input parameters are, e.g.,

```
n = 1000000;
d = 3;
m = 32;
x = RandomReal[{0., 1. - $MachineEpsilon}, {n, d}];
```

For performance, it is crucial that the resulting $n \times d \times m$ tensor is a packed array of `Integer`s. As you can see below, I have tried already several things. But in view of the fact that actually *nothing has to be computed* as the mantissas of the machine precision numbers are actually stored in binary, the timings are really disappointing.

```
ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray;
cf = Compile[{{z0, _Integer}, {base, _Integer}, {n, _Integer}},
   IntegerDigits[z0, base, n],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];


digits1 = ToPack[RealDigits[x, 2, m, -1][[All, All, 1]]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
digits2 = ToPack[IntegerDigits[IntegerPart[x 2.^m], 2, m]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
digits3 = Transpose[Table[Mod[IntegerPart[x 2.^k], 2], {k, 1, m}], {3, 1, 2}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
digits4 = Transpose[cf[IntegerPart[x 2.^m], 2, m], {1, 2, 3}]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

digits1 == digits2 == digits3 == digits4
```

> 11.3763
>
> 3.00342
>
> 1.7729
>
> 0.516279
>
> True

I have also tried to use `BitGet` but that was a couple of times slower than `RealDigits`.

In practice, I do not know in advance how many digits I need. So it would be even better to retrieve only the $k$-th digit at a time. In this case, the timings look as follows:

```
k = 4;
digit1 = ToPack[RealDigits[x, 2, 1, -k][[All, All, 1, -1]]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
digit2 = ToPack[
     IntegerDigits[IntegerPart[x 2.^k], 2, 1][[All, All, -1]]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
digit3 = Mod[IntegerPart[x 2.^k], 2]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
digit4 = cf[IntegerPart[x 2.^k], 2, 1][[All, All, -1]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First

digit1 == digit2 == digit3 == digit4
```

> 9.29457
>
> 2.31723
>
> 0.023894
>
> 0.238065
>
> True

So, `Mod` and `IntegerPart` seem to do quite a good job, but still, there is a multiplication involved for each digit to be extracted.

**Does anybody know of a fast, low-level way to retrieve the digits?**

Comment: What I'd try for raw speed is write a C plugin where you cast the `double` into an `unsigned long long int` and extract the bits directly by masking, using info from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: Correction: I've written a minimalistic C plugin that extracts a single binary digit directly by bit masking a `uint64_t` version of the double number. Even with all safety checks off, and MTensor processing inside the C function (i.e. only one function call for a large list of input numbers) this plugin just about as fast as your `digit3`. Not worth the trouble. In any case, as your `digit3` takes only about 8 nanoseconds per conversion, I'm wondering what speed goal you had in mind?

Comment: Thank you @Roman. This is both disappointing and encouraging at the same time. ;)

Comment: It's a shame `BitAnd` and `BitShiftRight` don't do what you think they would do on reals.

Answer (score 3):

### *Not a complete answer*

---

We can squeeze out a bit more speed by using `BitAnd` instead of `Mod` and `BitShiftLeft` instead of multiplication in your `digit3` calculation.

```
Mod[IntegerPart[x 2.^k], 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.015
> ```

```
BitAnd[IntegerPart[BitShiftLeft[x, k]], 1]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> ```
> 0.010
> ```

```
Mod[IntegerPart[x 2.^k], 2] == BitAnd[IntegerPart[BitShiftLeft[x, k]], 1]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

I sought a solution that masked the bits via combinations of `BitAnd` and `BitShiftRight`, but to my surprise they don't work on `Real` as you might think.

```
BitAnd[1.0, 1]
```

> ```
> BitAnd[1, 1.]
> ```

```
BitShiftRight[1.0, 1]
```

> ```
> 0.5
> ```

Though in its defense, C doesn't support bitwise operations on floats or doubles without casting to an integer type first.

Something like

```
double x = 1.0;
long n = *((long*)&x);
n >>= 1;
x = *((double*)&n);
```

gives `1.11875e-154` rather than `0.5`, and it behaves how we might expect it to.

We can do something similar in WL through `BinarySerialize` and extracting bits by masking.

```
MantissaDigit[arr_?Developer`PackedArrayQ, k_Integer] /; $ByteOrdering == -1 && $SystemWordLength == 64 && 1 <= k <= 52 :=
  Block[{blvl1, blvl2, dims, start, bytes, bits},
    blvl1 = 6 - Quotient[k+3, 8];
    blvl2 = 8 - Mod[k+4, 8, 1];
    dims = Dimensions[arr];
    start = blvl1 - 8(Times @@ dims);

    bytes = BinarySerialize[arr][[start ;; -1 ;; 8]];

    bits = BitAnd[BitShiftRight[Normal[bytes], blvl2], 1];

    ArrayReshape[bits, dims]
  ]
```

Note that this implementation depends on `$ByteOrdering` and `$SystemWordLength`.

This however is slower than the `digit3` technique:

```
MantissaDigit[x, k]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.021, Null}
> ```

One bottleneck is applying `Normal`, which is needed since bitwise operations don't work on `ByteArray`.